# Using the Outlook API in PowerShell to calculate mail transfer times

Tags: api, powershell, email, outlook

**1** - So I have the following script that retrieves the 12th email from my Outlook Inbox (I know that the `foreach` is not quite necessary at the moment):

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")


  foreach($mail in $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Items(12) )
  {
    Write-Host "Mail subject: " $mail.TaskSubject
    Write-Host "Sent on: " $mail.SentOn
    Write-Host "Received on: "$mail.ReceivedTime
    $time = $mail.ReceivedTime -= $mail.SentOn
  }
```

Output:

> Mail Subject: Buy shoes
>
> Sent on: 4/5/2017 20:10:15
>
> Received on:4/5/2017 20:10:25

I'm able to retrieve the sending and receiving time but I'm unable to substract them for each other to see how long it took for the email to get on its way.

I tried to output the `$time` variable but its empty and it doesn't show any errors. How would I correct this?

> 

**2** - Is it possible to get the email header using this API? I have tried to get around it but I assume it's not possible without other libraries (since the property `EmailHeader` does not exist?

> 

**3** - I need an email 'expert' for my next question. When I check the header of the email, I noticed that the `SentOn`  and `ReceivedTime` are nowhere to be found in the email header. Sometimes I can find times that are a few seconds more or less as the one in my script but in other occasions I find 0 comparable results.

Why is this?

Comment: Is `-=` a typo here? It doesn't seem to be a valid operator when used in that location.

Comment: yes it is thank you very much for noticing

Comment: Have you got any idea about the other seperate questions in my main question Mark? Just wondering

Comment: To the person who down voted: where in my sub-questions was I being ""too broad""? Care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use TimeSpan function....How, in this case I am not so sure at present still playing. Maybe you will get it quicker! Example of the function

```
$Starttime=(GET-DATE)

$Endtime=[datetime]”04/21/2017 00:00”

NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $Starttime –End $Endtime
```

Returns

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : -11
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : -1
Milliseconds      : -987
Ticks             : -396019872099
TotalDays         : -0.458356333447917
TotalHours        : -11.00055200275
TotalMinutes      : -660.033120165
TotalSeconds      : -39601.9872099
TotalMilliseconds : -39601987.2099
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wasn't aware about this. But isn't the `-` sign wrong?